# Possible to bypass Azure Function App Azure AD authentication for a single function and expose it by function key instead?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-functions, azure-authentication

I have an Azure Function App protected by integrated Azure AD authentication (configured via the "Express" setup in portal).

This enables AAD auth for all functions in the app, and any HTTP triggered functions inside the function app need to have "Anonymous" as the auth level.

But I need to expose just one of these HTTP triggers to an external vendor that cannot perform token-based authentication calls. It can call a fixed URI only (no auth headers etc).

I understand I can create a separate function app for this function, but I really do not want to do so if possible.

I know it's also possible to put Azure API management in front of the function app, but again I'd prefer avoiding the extra layer/cost.

So my question is, is it possible to have this single function bypass token-based AAD auth and become accessible to an outside caller via function key or some fixed API key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do that.

When you configure the AAD auth in the function app, it applies to the whole function app, you could not have this single function bypass AAD auth.